# Reversing an array with push and shift methods

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am trying to write a function for reverse arrays with push and shift methods but it doesn't work.

```
function reverseArrayInPlace(array) {
    for (let i = 0; i < array.length - 1; i++) {
        array.push(array.shift);
    }
    return array;
}
```

I guess for loop is looping forever because I am running code in eloquentjavascript's website and I get the following message when running the code "This code has been running for 2 seconds. Abort it?" What is wrong in this code?

Comment: `shift()` not `shift` ... you have to call the method

Comment: Still doesn't work @charlietfl - `[1, 2, 3]` -> `[3, 1, 2]`.

Comment: @JackBashford There's two questions hidden in one here. The first one is the typographical error, the second one is the wrong algorithmic approach. Fixing one doesn't automatically fix the other.

Comment: @charlietfl Thank you. The actual problem was not calling method. It is still wrong but after seeing the result, I understood logical part.

Comment: Can sort logic out a lot easier when browser doesn't freeze

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's two problems in your current code: one is a typo, the other is the algorithm.

Firstly, you're currently not calling shift:

```js
array.push(array.shift);
// Missing () -------^
```

The second issue is your proposed algorithm won't reverse an array, it will shift it.
Allow me to demonstrate:

Given an initial array of `[1, 2, 3, 4]`, here's what your algorithm does.

```js
// Initial state
┌───┬───┬───┬───┐
│ 1 │ 2 │ 3 │ 4 │
└───┴───┴───┴───┘

// Shift one...            // ...and push it
┌───┬───┬───┐    ┌───┐     ┌───┬───┬───┬───┐
│ 2 │ 3 │ 4 │ -> │ 1 │     │ 2 │ 3 │ 4 │ 1 │
└───┴───┴───┘    └───┘     └───┴───┴───┴───┘

// Shift one...            // ...and push it
┌───┬───┬───┐    ┌───┐     ┌───┬───┬───┬───┐
│ 3 │ 4 │ 1 │ -> │ 2 │     │ 3 │ 4 │ 1 │ 2 │
└───┴───┴───┘    └───┘     └───┴───┴───┴───┘

// Etc
```

As you can see, your algorithm doesn't reverse the array, but instead appends the items from the start to the end in the same order.

You can see some alternative options in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32418443/reverse-array-in-place), which this is technically a duplicate of, aside from the typo.

Comment: Curious what sort of tool you used to create diagram?

Comment: @charlietfl It's just [box-drawing characters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Box-drawing_character) in a code block.

Comment: But manually written? Or some sort of editor?

Comment: Yes, there are tools both online and offline that do it for you, but for something as small as this it's faster to do it by hand.

Answer (score 0):

You are not actually calling the method, you are just passing it as a reference.

To make it more clear, do this:

```
let temp_value = array.shift()
array.push(temp_value)
```