# Why does the pop() method stop working when used within a map method?

Tags: javascript, arrays, dictionary

I want to reverse an array in place without using reverse method. I tried the following code:

```js
function reverseArray(arr) {
  return arr.map(() => {
    return arr.pop()
  })
}
console.log(reverseArray([1, 2, 3, 4]));
//logs [4,3,undefined,undefined]
```

Using dev tools debugger, this is what logs in the console: `(4) [4, 3, empty × 2]`.

`arr.pop()` returns undefined if called on an empty array but it shouldn't be empty in this case, to my understanding.

Question: what's happening? Why are the first two elements printing correctly and the rest aren't?

Comment: You're removing elements from the array while you're iterating over it.

Comment: There's already a reverse method for arrays.  Why reinvent the wheel?

Comment: `return arr[ arr.length - 1 - i ];` should do the job

Comment: @Taplar The question is specifically about not using this method.

Comment: I get that.  If this is for learning, cool.  Otherwise, it's just a waste of time.

Comment: You shouldn't be using `map()` if you want the result to be in the original array. It always returns a new array.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're removing elements from the array while you're iterating over it. The [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) says:

> The range of elements processed by map is set before the first invocation of callback. ... Elements that are deleted after the call to map begins and before being visited are not visited.

So `map()` determines at the beginning that it will iterate 4 times, creating an array with 4 elements.

On the first iteration, `arr.pop()` removes `arr[3]`. On the second iteration it removes `arr[2]`.

The third iteration expects to process `arr[2]`. But since that element doesn't exist any more, it doesn't call the callback function, and just stores `undefined` in the result array. The same thing happens on the fourth iteration.

You could iterate over a copy of the array.

```js
function reverseArray(arr) {
  return [...arr].map(() => {
    return arr.pop()
  })
}
console.log(reverseArray([1, 2, 3, 4]));
```

Comment: The problem with this solution is, that it is not in place like requested

Comment: The original code isn't in place, either. `map()` always creates a new array.

Comment: While that's true, the question was asking for a in place solution. That's why I was wondering

Answer (score 0):

The problem is, that you `pop` some elements and therefore, they don't exist in the array anymore. So, the first two elements are `pop`ed and two other ones are written in those spots, but internally they don't exist anymore in the mean time.

There are also many other (better) solutions like this one (from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32418443/reverse-array-in-place)):

```
function reverse (array) {
  var i = 0,
      n = array.length,
      middle = Math.floor(n / 2),
      temp = null;

  for (; i < middle; i += 1) {
     temp = array[i];
     array[i] = array[n - 1 - i];
     array[n - 1 - i] = temp;
  }
}
```